# Add verification between Client and DDNS Server

Tags: linux-networking

I'm new to networking and I have some questions want to ask.

A client site browser able to request from DDNS Server to obtain the website IP address that client want to redirect to, thus it helps client route to that specific website.

Is there any possibilities to add verification before client is authorized to request from DDNS Server? For example, username, password or even IP address.

Comment: Please rewrite your question:

Which environment? Public internet or a company/campus intranet?
Please stat also who update the DDNS server: there is a client on host or other mechanism ...

Answer (score 2):

I think your are mixing up terms.

**[DDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS)** , also know as **DynDNS** and **dynamic DNS** is used to set/**update a DNS record** so that systems with dynamic ip-addresses can always be addressed by the same hostname.

Such update requests are always authenticated.

The rest of your question seems to be about normal DNS resolving -  DNS lookup requests are not authenticated and secured with a username/password.

If you need to secure access to a server you do that by securing the srver, or the website, not by securing the hostname lookups, as an attacker will always be able to connect to a server without a hostname, by using the server's ip-address.